# http post request python. request.post changing JSON

Tags: python, json, request

Hey I am new to python so sorry if this is simple.

I have JSON text formatted for a post request. I have got this working in POSTMAN (a chrome extension that post the request) but I am trying to automate it in python. The JSON works in Postman but throws back an error that the JSON is incorrectly formatted if I use request.post

```
import requests
import csv
import json

with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    data = {"ids": 
        [{"id" : row[0], "timestamp":"20150831"} for row in csvreader],
          "attributes":[
            {
                "name":"home"
            },
            {
                "name":"work"
            }
          ]
        }


json1 = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print(json1)

requestpost = requests.post('url', json=json1, auth=('username','password')) 
print(requestpost)
```

Comment: What is the format of a row in the csv file? What is the exact error u're getting?

Comment: It seems like you are using the string literal 'url' instead of a variable URL

Comment: What is the JSON format expected by the server. I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted. Is the error a python error or an error returned from the web service?

Comment: I removed the json.dump line and it seemed to work. I am not sure why. I think request.post must be doing the same thing as json.dump perhaps